# Is there a way to highlight the legend of a dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

The problem can be seen in any multiple variable plot of dygraph when the colors are close to each other, and especially if you are like me who is not very good in identifying small differences in colours (my wife can do a much better job than me).

The best way is to see the picture of a dygraph and the mouse pointed on any one line. [image]
As you can see the colours of variable `z` and `short` are very close to green.

Is there  a way to highlight (with say a rectangle) around the pointed series on the legend as well. I know we can use `dyHighlight()` to highlight the data series.

If someone wants to replicate the dygraph here is the data and code.

Here is a data.frame (of just 10 rows) in dput format.

```
structure(list(ts = structure(c(1636488540L, 1636488600L, 1636488660L, 
1636488720L, 1636488780L, 1636488840L, 1636488900L, 1636488960L, 
1636489020L, 1636489080L, 1636489140L), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), x = c(-1.47069335096148, -3.36409786063375, 
-3.47740281050692, -0.255068206704506, 5.22759893683639, -10.3043374092728, 
-5.2344716901776, -9.78183898579815, -3.22880795465383, 10.605420513646, 
-3.89232017758796), y = c(-43.384448866304, -46.7485467269378, 
-50.2259495374447, -50.4810177441492, -45.2534188073128, -55.5577562165856, 
-60.7922279067632, -70.5740668925614, -73.8028748472152, -63.1974543335692, 
-67.0897745111571), z = c(-137.821501091824, -132.046751108584, 
-140.358945130686, -147.455514008532, -145.960386088907, -151.292192768048, 
-161.603402930662, -186.92405101591, -205.16916964654, -207.574396073346, 
-204.090103691941), fuel = c(852.178498908176, 857.953248891416, 
849.641054869314, 842.544485991468, 844.039613911093, 838.707807231952, 
828.396597069338, 803.07594898409, 784.83083035346, 782.425603926654, 
785.909896308058), delta = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    short = c(-8.8926709311977, 6.5109558655754, 5.24159847904127, 
    -3.34476928169295, -8.13888499708287, -19.2454416594633, 
    -21.2444577999751, -39.4685370073786, -59.2087835576331, 
    -56.2822033052981, -42.48670076128), long = c(-178.435062392844, 
    -179.31344224667, -187.306132052743, -185.62097109537, -176.874913772529, 
    -172.952666784266, -167.386770377762, -184.70364909417, -196.140010827552, 
    -194.056786969029, -182.415749904105)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Run the code

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(dygraphs)

# assign the above data to an R object say dputvar - note it is just 10 rows.
# you will not see the same rich chart as in the picture but the problem can be replicated in these 10 lines also

as.data.table(dputvar) %>% 
dygraph() %>% 
dySeries(name = "fuel",strokeWidth = 3) %>% 
dyHighlight()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better if you select your own set of colours so that they are distinct and not similar to one another? Something like this:

```
mydygraph <- dygraph(as.data.table(dputvar))
for (i in c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'black', 'purple')) {
 mydygraph <- dySeries(a, strokeWidth = 3, color = i)
}
mydygraph
```

This way you can choose distinct colours. You can add colours in the following formats: `"#AABBCC"` or `"rgb(255,100,200)"` or `"yellow"`.  You can read more at `?dySeries`.

[image]

Comment: Good idea @LyzadeR. Note: your code may be corrected as it gives an error. We have to pass one color at a time.

Comment: It should actually work fine like this (using the data set that you dput above). I run it as is to produce the above graph :). But maybe you have a different data set.

Comment: Even the same dputvar gives the same error: `Error in currColors[[series$name]] <- color : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace`

Comment: I have `‘dygraphs’ version 1.1.1.6`

Comment: Indeed, I had an older version. I updated the answer with 1.1.1.6 as well. Now it should be working with the above code in an automated way

Answer (score 0):

While the answer with distinct colours might satisfy you. I will still provide an answer to your initial question for the benefit of others who came here with the same issue.

You cold achieve legend highlight with `dyCSS` and `dyHighlight`:

```
dygraph(dat) %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 3)) %>%
  dyCSS(textConnection("
     .dygraph-legend > span.highlight { display: inline; background-color: #B0B0B0;}
  "))
```

Here `dygraph-legend` says that we want to modify the legend. `span.highlight` to modify the highlighted series. `background-color: #B0B0B0;` modification to the background colour.

[image]

You could also just hide all legends except the highlighted ones:

```
dygraph(dat) %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 3)) %>%
  dyCSS(textConnection("
     .dygraph-legend > span { display: none; }
     .dygraph-legend > span.highlight { display: inline}
  "))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good @Jav. I will test your code soon and if it works, will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.